# How to give SharePoint Designer 2013 access to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How do I give SharePoint Designer 2013 access to SharePoint Online?

When logging in on SharePoint Designer with a Global Admin account that has access as an Additional Admin on the site, I get an error:

"You do not have permission to access this site in SharePoint Designer."

According to this Dummies article, there is supposed to be a SharePoint Designer Settings option under Site Collection Administration section in Site Settings:

https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/sharepoint/managing-sharepoint-designer-access/

I do not see it there.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

You need to first click on "SharePoint Designer Settings" as shown in the pic below.

[image: From Site Collection Administration page]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for this, although the setting did not appear there. I found out the reason as I do not have sufficient privileges to activate SharePoint Designer. I am a Global Admin. Would you know if I need to be anything else?

Comment: I am still getting this:

![Valid XHTML](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/bddfa512-5f5b-410e-b6f4-a61cd08a2e4d).

Comment: @newbiecoder, just to be sure, you have checked that you are the Administrator for the Site Collection too? if you haven't; add your self to Site collection administrators.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that these are all Teams connected sites I am unable to access through SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Thank you so much

I found I couldn't modify the Primary Site Admin since it was a Teams connected site. I followed this article:

https://jobs.collab365.community/how-to-gain-access-to-microsoft-teams-sites-using-sharepoint-designer/

I am now able to access the site through SharePoint Designer!

Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try to narrow down this issue:

1. Check if you have turned on the **Custom Script** option via Classic SharePoint admin center > settings > Custom Script (`https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx`).
2. Open the **SharePoint Designer Settings** page via this link and then select “Enable SharePoint Designer”: 
   `https://<siteURL>/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx`
3. If you still get error after enabling this option, install the [Service Pack 1 for SharePoint Designer 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817441/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1).

---

**UPDATE:**

You are getting Access Denied error possibly because custom script is not enabled on the site level.

Please run the PowerShell commands below as a global admin.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com

Set-SPOsite "<SiteURL>" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, that helped me to see the SharePoint Designer settings as it was not listed under Site Collection Administration.

I also found the reason, because as soon as I accessed the link and tried to apply any of the settings, I got an access denied error.

I am a Global Admin on the tenant. Should I be anything else?

Comment: I am still getting this:

![Valid XHTML](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/bddfa512-5f5b-410e-b6f4-a61cd08a2e4d).

Comment: @newbiecoder I've modified the answer. Please check the update.

Comment: I have checked and scripting is enabled. Thanks for that.

Would it have anything to do with the fact that these are all Teams connected sites I am unable to access through SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Thank you so much

I found I couldn't modify the Primary Site Admin since it was a Teams connected site. I followed this article:

https://jobs.collab365.community/how-to-gain-access-to-microsoft-teams-sites-using-sharepoint-designer/

I am now able to access the site through SharePoint Designer!

Thanks to all who contributed.